# Windows phone 8.1 Flyout hide with behaviour issue

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

What's wrong with the following behavior xaml , nothing happens at run time ( not even a exception).  I'm trying to close flyout without code behind logic.

```
<AppBarButton HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Label="Pin to dashboard"
                          x:Name="pinBtn">
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <Flyout x:Name="flyout"
                            Placement="Full">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock Text="Save as"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="16" />
                            <TextBox Width="275"
                                     Style="{StaticResource RoundedTextBox}"
                                     FontFamily="Global User Interface" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Button Content="Save"
                                        Width="50" />
                                <Button x:Name="button"
                                        Content="Cancel"
                                        Width="50"
                                        Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                     <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior x:Name="eventTriggerBehavior" EventName="Click">
                                            <Core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Flyout, ElementName=pinBtn}"
                                                                   MethodName="Hide" />
                                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Flyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what is "Core" in Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors. Which library are you using. Could be an issue with that.

Comment: You can use TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=flyout}" instead of the TargetObject="{Binding Flyout, ElementName=pinBtn}". Also your name is lowercase: x:Name="flyout". I think it's important. But it doesn't work anyway. So I use the Click="..." button handler in the code behind file

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote [a blog post](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/05/08/Creating-a-behavior-or-action-to-close-a-Flyout-from-a-control-within-the-Flyout.aspx) on how you can accomplish this with a custom behavior or action.

When the button is clicked, you'll want to walk up the visual tree until you find the FlyoutPresenter, then get it's Parent as a popup and set IsOpen to false;

```
var flyout = element.GetVisualParent<FlyoutPresenter>();
if (flyout != null)
{
    var popup = flyout.Parent as Popup;
    if (popup != null)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `element` in `var flyout = element.GetVisualParent<FlyoutPresenter>();` ?

Comment: That's the FrameworkElement as part of the `IAction`. The blog post goes into more details

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a custom action and with the help of WinRT XAML Toolkit.

```
/// <summary>
/// Using MVVM to close a flyout
/// </summary>
public class CloseFlyoutAction : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        var element = sender as DependencyObject;
        var flyout = element.GetFirstAncestorOfType<FlyoutPresenter>();
        var popup = flyout.Parent as Popup;
        if (popup != null)
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Cancel">
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <common:CloseFlyoutAction />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am sure you have to handle the Save and Cancel button on code behind so why not close the flyout from code behind as  well.

```
<Button x:Name="buttonCancel"
     Content="Cancel" Width="50" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
     Click="buttonCancel_Click">


private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Dismiss the Flyout after the action is confirmed.
        pinBtn.Flyout.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Because he wants to do it without the code behind logic. Like me

Comment: null reference with this one.