# Close UWP flyout with listview item click

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to close a flyout on a listview item click. The problem is that during runtime, the CallMethodAction can't find the hide method of the flyout menu. How can I fix this?

```
    <Flyout x:Name="UnitFlyout">
        <ListView x:Name="ArmyUnitListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ArmyUnitCollection}}" SelectionMode="Single"  >
             <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ArmyListDataGroupTemplate}" />
              </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                 </Style>
               </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
               <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                     <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                           <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AddUnitCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ArmyUnitListView}" />
                            <core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="UnitFlyout" MethodName="Hide"/>
                      </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
         </ListView>
    </Flyout>
```

Comment: I guess it should be `TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=UnitFlyout}"`

Comment: now it doesn't crash but it doesn't work still :(

Comment: refer this link. Hope it will solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066687/windows-phone-8-1-flyout-hide-with-behaviour-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a demo and reproduced the problem.The reason lies on the ElementName binding to popups.

> ElementName bindings do not work within Flyout’s and other popups

Please see [this Case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45f81280-c333-46fb-aa69-43a2b1d656cc/buttonflyout-bug?forum=w81prevwCsharp).

I found this [blog](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/using-windows-8-1-flyout-xaml-control-with-mvvm/), which offers a workaround to fix this problem. And I've tried it with a demo,which works fine.

In your case, you can copy the `FlyoutHelpers` (in blog) class to your project; And add `IsFlyoutOpen` and `SendCommand` to your ViewModel like below:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand SendCommand { get; set; }// bind this to your xaml

    public List<String> MyData { get; set; }

    private bool isFlyoutOpen;
    public bool IsFlyoutOpen// bind this to your xaml
    {
        get { return isFlyoutOpen; }
        set { this.Set(() => IsFlyoutOpen, ref isFlyoutOpen, value); }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        SendCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            // Doing processing...
            IsFlyoutOpen = false;
        });
        MyData = new List<string> { "winffee", "123", "this Data" };//this is sample data
    }
}
```

And Bind the commands and properties to your xaml:

```
<Flyout x:Name="UnitFlyout" 
        local:FlyoutHelpers.Parent="{Binding ElementName=myBtn}" 
        local:FlyoutHelpers.IsOpen="{Binding IsFlyoutOpen,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView x:Name="ArmyUnitListView"  SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
         <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
             <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
             </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=ArmyUnitListView}">
            <!--<core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AddUnitCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ArmyUnitListView}" />-->
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SendCommand}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     </ListView>
</Flyout>
```

Here is my entire Demo: [FlyoutSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/FlyoutSample)